# Chat-Langchain: Streamhandler streams the chat history as well as the final answer in the output. why?

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, langchain

## [Please see this first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlBLw.png)

See how the chatbot streams the chat history along with the final answer. The ideal scenario would be that it streams only the final output answer.

Please go through this [github repo](https://github.com/langchain-ai/chat-langchain). I have changed nothing except adding a vector database and replacing the chatvectordbchain with the conversationalretrievalchain. However, the problem existed before I made these changes.

I believe I have to make changes in the [callback.py](https://github.com/langchain-ai/chat-langchain/blob/master/callback.pyfile), specifically in the StreamingLLMCallbackHandler class.

But I do not know how to proceed from this. Any suggestions would help.

Thank you.

I tried to reproduce their work and were expecting a chatbot like application that can support any vector database. It works as it should be with one exception. The output stream always includes the chat history along with the final answer.